# JProfiler, Want to store data measurment in disk automaticly without using JProfiler GUI?

Tags: jprofiler

I use JProfiler to measure Memory used, CPU and Garbage collection for my application. I can see all those measurement in JProfiler GUI. Also I am able to store data for all mentioned measurements in disk after finishing the test using options in GUI in order to generate a nice report using excel for example.

But I want to do the same task automatically, for example when the test complete I want to store all measurement automatically in disk without using GUI.

Any help?

Thank you

Ibrahim

Answer (score 0):

This is done with [offline profiling](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/offline/offline.html).

In the "Triggers" section of the session settings, you can set up triggers that are executed for certain events, such as entry / exit of selected methods, timers, low heap / high CPU conditions, JVM start and exit and others.

[image]

Each trigger has a list of actions that control the profiling agent. Among other things, they can start and stop recording and save snapshots.

[image]

You can then export data from the saved snapshots programmatically with the command line utility [jpexport](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/export/export.html).